# Get js0 data without joy publishing

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, joy-node, joystick, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to protect the input data stream into my robot, but not by subscribing to joy.  Rather I'd like to add joy code into my cpp or just directly get the info from /dev/input/js0.  I am using ROS Kinetic.

I've searched and haven't been able to quite find the answer that will work with ROS.

I appreciate any help, and would be happy to answer any questions to help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300588/get-js0-data-without-joy-publishing/) by [jamesR](https://answers.ros.org/users/36985/jamesr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-14**:
Well: my first question would be: what do you hope to gain by that? I'm particularly interested in your "I'm trying to protect the input data stream to my robot" remark there.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-08-14**:
You could always start by [modifying the source code from the joystick_drivers](https://github.com/ros-drivers/joystick_drivers/tree/master/joy) package to do what you desire with the `/dev/js0` data instead of publishing it to `/joy`

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-08-15**:
Are you trying to 'hide' the joystick values from the wider ROS system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that you can not do what you need by setting the device or device name parameters in joy?

You might also consider combining this with some udev rules.

---

Originally posted by [qnetjoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27506/qnetjoe/) with karma: 30 on 2018-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0